# How to remove colour background into transparent or other colour with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

My video is like in this picture. I need to remove blue background into transparent or other colour. How can I make it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcaAP.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take some time to follow the [Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, you're on a questions/answers website about programming. Can you elaborate your question ? Provide us the relevant code you wrote (and at least what you've tried so far) for your question (You can also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: The name of the effect you seek is *chroma keying*. FFmpeg has two filters for this: [chromakey](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#chromakey) if you're working in the YUV space, and [colorkey](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#colorkey) for RGB space. Their result will be cruder than pro-grade keyers but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Thx so much for you help.I will try even my FFMPEG skill is very poor haha.

Comment: I try to approach it but there is some problem. My blue background is not real blue. It consist of a lot of blue shade. Could I remove that all blue color? or Could I set range of blue color and remove it?